how to determine application preferences location
I just installed some old software from a few years ago (i can't get it to run because it is expired and out-of-production (123DMake)
Even when using runas software (allows you to change the date and time), it wouldn't run - meaning that instead of checking the current date/time, it must be pulling from some kind of cache or file.
Running processmonitor when launching the app and filtering by PID, i didnt see it writing to any file in %appdata% or anything like that.
I uninstalled the app and installed a newer version, and when i opened the newer version, it ran, and it remembered the last project directory that i had used over a year ago.
My question is - what is the best way to see all the files, settings, caches, etc that an application uses / writes and reads from?  I'm curious what I missed.
Thanks very much!
